# Make port and address configurable

Tags: jqassistant

Can you please make port 7474 configurable and also setting Neo4J's property "org.neo4j.server.webserver.address"?

By default I suggest that org.neo4j.server.webserver.address is set to "0.0.0.0", providing remote access if firewall settings allow it.

Answer (score 2):

jQAssistant currently uses Neo4j as an embedded database, thus the configuration of the server is not directly accessible as described in the Neo4j documentation.
There should be not much effort providing these settings as parameters to the Maven plugin or command line interface, e.g.

```
jqassistant.sh server --serverAddress 0.0.0.0 --serverPort 7474
```

If you're interested in that change create an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/buschmais/jqassistant/issues) and it will be available with the next release.